# How to fix 'Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')' error in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The Error:

```
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
```

The Part of Code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const config = require("./config.json");

const client = new Discord.Client({
    restTimeOffset: 0,
    allowedMentions: {
        parse: [
            /* "roles", "users", "everyone" */
        ],
        repliedUser: false,
    },
    partials: [ "MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ],
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        //Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING
    ],
    presence: {
        activity: {
            name: `Private Bot`,
            type: "WATCHING",
        },
        status: "online",
    },
});
```

how to fix it?

I'm still new and i just follow the tutorial on Youtube. I've checked repeatedly, it was same. but why? i still got an error :(

Answer (score -1):

I think do `npm i discord.js@13.6.0` in the console